# How to call a method in child component from a list of components in parent component in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I have child component which is basically a list component which is iterated in the parent component's template. I want to call a method resides in the child component from the parent component. I want to call the method belong one of the many components.

For example, this is my child component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list-item',
    template: '<li>{{value}}</li>',
})
export class ListItem implements OnInit {
    @Input value: number;

    changeValue(newValue) {
      this.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

And this is how my parent component looks like -

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list',
    template: '<div><list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value"></list-item></div>',
})
export class List implements OnInit {
    // Some code to call **changeValue** 
    // method of the let's say the second 
    // list-item from the template
}
```

I know about **@ViewChild** decorators but it seems work for only the first one.

> Consider the child component as an independent reusable component. So use of pub/sub is not a good idea.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a separate "model" class to encapsulate the `value` property and the `changeValue` method. The parent component would call `changeValue` on these objects and the child component would react to these changes via Angular 2's change detection mechanism. If this sounds like a viable alternative but it is not clear, I can add more details in an answer for you.

Comment: As I said, consider the child component as an independent component. We can't make any modification to that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, but if you need to... 
Since the component is a class, you should be able to access its **public** methods. You will need to provide the child class in your parent **providers: [ChildComponent]**.

```
      @Component({
      selector: 'parent',
      templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
      providers: [ChildComponent]
    })
    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private child: ChildComponent){}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.child.foo();
    }

}

 @Component({
      selector: 'child',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],

    })
    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(){}

  public foo() {
    console.log('FOO')
  }

}
```